# Calculating some probabilities with a mouse moving along an $8 \times n$ grid

Tags: probability

We are given the following grid and a mouse positioned in the bottom left 
 -- $(0, 0)$ -- corner that moves to the right with probability $p = 0.7$ and up with $q = 0.3$ (so it either moves right or up):

[image: Grid]

And are asked the following questions:

> 1. What is the probability that the mouse will reach the point $(8, 5)$?
> 2. If the dots along the topmost row, meaning $(0, 8), (1, 8), \ldots$, are exits, what is the probability that the mouse will reach an exit in no more than $13$ steps?

I solved number 1. in the following manner: in order for the mouse to reach $(8, 5)$, it has to make $5$ moves up (or equivalently, $8$ moves right), giving us a probability of $\displaystyle \binom{13}{5} p^8 q^5$. Is this correct?

---

As for number 2., I am a bit stuck. I tried the following: in order for the mouse to reach an exit in no more than $13$ steps, it has to reach the exit in $8, 9, \ldots, 13$ steps (it cannot do it in less than $8$ steps).  The probability to reach exit $(0, 8)$ is $\displaystyle \binom{8}{8} p^0 q^8 = q^8$, the probability to reach exit $(1, 8)$ is $\displaystyle \binom{9}{8} p^1 q^8 - \binom{8}{8} p^0 q^8$, and so on. Now, this subtraction part is where I'm unsure. I added it like this because I *think* that $\displaystyle \binom{9}{8} p^1 q^8$ somehow counts the exit at $(0, 8)$, too. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing fine.  Yes ${9 \choose 8}p^1q^8$ counts (some of) the earlier case over, because you can get to $(1,8)$ by eight ups (which gets you to $(0,8)$) followed by a right.  One way to avoid this is to assume the grid continues upward and the mouse makes a full $13$ moves, then ask the chance that it has made at least eight upward moves.  You add the chances that it is at $(0,13), (1,12) \dots (5,8)$, which you know how to calculate.